# Why won't my DataMapper record save when I pass it the user it belongs to?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I have set up a simple has-many and belongs-to association using DataMapper with Sinatra. My User model has many 'peeps', and my Peep model belongs to user. See below for the classes....

I am able to successfully create a new peep which belongs to a particular user, by passing the user_id directly into the peep on initialization, like this:

**Method 1**

`new_peep = Peep.create(content: params[:content], user_id: current_user.id)`

This adds 1 to Peep to Peep.count.

However, my understanding is that I should be able to create the association by assigning the current_user to new_peep.user. But when I try that, the peep object won't save.

I've tried this:

**Method 2**

`new_peep = Peep.create(content: params[:content], user: current_user)`

*Current user here is User.get(session[:current_user_id])*

The resulting new_peep has an id of nil, but *does* have user_id set to the current_user's id. New_peep looks exactly like the new_peep that successfully gets created using Method 1, except it has no id because it hasn't successfully saved. I've tried calling new_peep.save separately, but I still get the below for the peep object:

`<Peep @id=nil @content="This is a test peep" @created_at=#<DateTime: 2016-05-08T12:42:52+01:00 ((2457517j,42172s,0n),+3600s,2299161j)> @user_id=1>, @errors={}`

*Note that there are no validation errors. Most problems other people seem to have had with saving records come down to a validation criteria not being met.*

I assumed this was something to do with the belongs_to association not working, but I can (after creating new_peep using Method 1 above) still call new_peep.user and access the correct user. So it seems to me the belongs_to is working as a reader but not a setter.

This problem also means I cannot create a peep by adding one into the user.peeps collection then saving user, which means there's virtually no point in peep belonging to user.

I've seen other people have had problems saving records that don't have any changes to save - but this is a completely new record, so all its attributes are being updated.

I'd really like to know what's going on - this has baffled me for too long!

Here are my classes:

```
class Peep

    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :content, Text
    property :created_at, DateTime

    belongs_to :user, required: false

    def created_at_formatted
        created_at.strftime("%H:%M, %A %-d %b %Y")
    end

end


class User

    include DataMapper::Resource
    include BCrypt

    attr_accessor :password_confirmation
    attr_reader :password

    property :id, Serial
    property :email, String, unique: true, required: true
    property :username, String, unique: true, required: true
    property :name, String
    property :password_hash, Text

    def self.authenticate(params)
        user = first(email: params[:email])
        if user && Password.new(user.password_hash) == params[:password]
            user
        else
            false
        end
    end

    def password=(actual_password)
        @password = actual_password
        self.password_hash = Password.create(actual_password)
    end

    validates_confirmation_of :password
    validates_presence_of :password

    has n, :peeps

end
```

Comment: Did you try calling valid? On the record before reading errors? In rails this is necessary to load the errors array

Comment: Thanks Max. Just tried. Valid? returns true for the record, and the errors collection is still empty.

Comment: Could you link to a repo or post a full script to test it out? I don't think your assertion that "there is virtually no point in peep belonging to user" is correct. I don't see the `user: current_user` syntax as much more than sugar for `user_id: current_user.id`. The `belongs_to :user` association is  basically sugar for `def user; User.find_by(id: self.user_id); end`. The `belongs_to` method is basically there to assist in writing less code.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Peep you don't create it through User, maybe that's why it has no primary id, since it belongs to User. Also you're assigning it the foreign key `user_id` as if you have a property defined as such. Although the database has it, in DataMapper you don't pass in the foreign key id, it does it for you.

Try replacing

```
new_peep = Peep.create(content: params[:content], user: current_user)
```

with:

```
new_peep = current_user.peeps.create(content: params[:content], created_at: Time.now)
```